# Non atomic transaction inside transaction.atomic() block in Django

Tags: django, django-models, transactions, django-orm, atomic

I would like to insert in db some objects directly inside transaction.atomic() block, not waiting that block finish.

### Why do I need this?

I need atomic block because of a business logic and without it, I could get invalid state.

But, I would like to track process. Process need to be updated inside block, because if executed after atomic block is finished, I only get 100% inserted.

### Example

for example, I would need something like this

```
def my_function(my_list, id):
    t = Task.objects.get(id)
    percent = int(100 / len(my_list))
    with transaction.atomic():
        for i in my_list:
            MyObject.objects.create(**i)
            t.progress = t.progress + percent
            t.save # This should not be atomic!!!!
```

### Not a solution

- I can't move the t.save outside the atomic block because it need to be updated along the code to track process.
- Directly inserting into database with

code

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(".... my update statement...")
```

I try and it doesn't work - it still insert after atomic block is finished.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to commit a single query within an atomic transaction.  If you elaborate on how the progress tracking is used, there may be different solution.